# Djanog error (DoesNotExist at /admin/ Profile matching query does not exist)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm working with someone's code. it's running perfectly on my local machine. I am easily able to create a superuser account. but when I'm trying to log in that account it's showing me these error messages. what should I do?

```
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
```

timelines.models.Profile.DoesNotExist: Profile matching query does not exist.
HTTP GET /admin/ 500 [0.12, 127.0.0.1:52697]

Comment: did you create profile object for your superuser ?

Comment: no, I created the superuser using command  "python manage.py createsuperuser"

Comment: raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
timelines.models.Profile.DoesNotExist: Profile matching query does not exist. HTTP GET /admin/ 500 [0.12, 127.0.0.1:52697]

Comment: this was the actual error

Comment: you may need to run migrations

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a user, and this user doesn't have a profile yet.

One option would be doing something like this:

```
users_without_profile = User.objects.filter(profile__isnull=True)
for user in users_without_profile:
    Profile.objects.create(user=user)
```

Another option would be to use signals. Something like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created: #if User was created
        Profile.objects.create(user = instance)

 @receiver(post_save, sender = User)
 def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.profile.save()
```

I had to make some assumptions since you don't provide a lot of information.

Comment: I was creating a superuser using createsuperuser command and it was created successfully. but when I'm trying to login it is showing this error:                                                                        raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
timelines.models.Profile.DoesNotExist: Profile matching query does not exist. HTTP GET /admin/ 500 [0.12, 127.0.0.1:52697]

Comment: Yes, it's because you probably created the profile model later on. Have you tried my answer? It should work.